# Python + Jinja2 - can't print the jinja2 template in mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, jinja2, mod-wsgi

Why can't I print the jinja2 template on my browser in mod_wsgi?

This is my python code,

```
import os
import MySQLdb
import jinja2

# This is our application object. It could have any name,
# except when using mod_wsgi where it must be "application"
def application(environ, start_response):

   # Open database connection
   db = MySQLdb.connect(user = "root", passwd = "xxxx", db = "python", host = "127.0.0.1")

   # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
   cursor = db.cursor()

   # execute SQL query using execute() method.
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

   # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
   data = cursor.fetchall()

   # disconnect from server
   cursor.close()
   db.close()

   templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath = os.path.dirname(__file__))

   # An environment provides the data necessary to read and
   # parse our templates.  We pass in the loader object here.
   JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(loader = templateLoader)

   # This constant string specifies the template file we will use.
   TEMPLATE_FILE = "/template/page.html"

   # Read the template file using the environment object.
   # This also constructs our Template object.
   template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)

   parsed_template = template.render(title = "Country list", users = data)
   print data
   print parsed_template

   response_body = parsed_template % (title = "Country list", users = data)

   status = '200 OK'

   response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),
                  ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
   start_response(status, response_headers)

   return [response_body]
```

Error,

Server error!

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> 127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.4

Any ideas what have I done wrong?

Comment: The line `response_body = parsed_template % (title = "Country list", users = data)` shouldn't be there - the call to `template.render` should have already generated a string with `{{title}}` and `{{users}}` replaced.

Comment: Look in the Apache error log, it should give you an error traceback as to why.